# strapi upgrade from 3.0.x alpha to beta

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, strapi

I have been following this tutorial to play around with `strapi`
https://strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi
But when I installed, I installed `alpha` instead of `beta`
I am trying to upgrade to `beta` so I followed the instructions here

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-alpha.26-to-beta.html

I followed the instructions to change modify `package.json` then I ran `npm i` which gave me an error of `notarget No matching version found for strapi-hook-knex@3.0.0-beta.x.`

then instead of what the documentation mentioned changing all `alpha` related to `beta.x`
`"strapi": "3.0.0-alpha.26.2"`  -> `"strapi": "3.0.0-beta.x"`
I did `"strapi": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5"`

which makes the command `npm i` ran successfully so I continued with the instructions.  After I am done, I tried running `strapi develop` I get an error of `error Error: Missing extensions folder. Please create one in your app root directory` so I added in the folder named `extensions` manually then try to start up `strapi develop` but then I get an error of `error Error: Cannot find module 'strapi-hook-bookshelf/lib/utils/'`

I tried removing `node_modules` clean npm cache and also the `.cache` folder within the project but none of those worked though.

Here is a complete modified `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "cms",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application.",
  "main": "./server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint api/**/*.js config/**/*.js plugins/**/*.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "knex": "latest",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "pg": "^7.13.0",
    "sqlite3": "latest",
    "strapi": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-admin": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-email-nodemailer": "^0.2.1",
    "strapi-hook-bookshelf": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-hook-knex": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5",
    "strapi-utils": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "email": "",
      "url": ""
    }
  ],
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "abcf5f65-060b-43f6-b98d-a4687fd81def"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x",
    "npm": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Anyone has idea what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions + help.

Current versions before upgrading strapi
Strapi - 3.0.0-alpha.26.2  (global)
Node - v10.17.0
npm - 6.11.3

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. I was able to resolve this by emptying my `/api` folder and the server started working again.

Comment: I would get error like `Error: You have some local plugins with the same name as npm installed plugins: `-content-manager.......` Also, isn't it weird to empty the whole `/api` folder since all the models and others are in there.